# I would like to match all the text between and including the td and /td tags

Tags: c#, html, regex

I would like to match all the text between and including the td and /td tags.
This is a sample within a much larger space.

```
    <td class="time">
        <span class="sTime">11:14<br>START</span>
        <span class="hTime">4/26/2014 11:14 AM</span>
        <span class="rot">3422</span>
    </td>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. 
It seems as though the hardest part for me is taking into account the new lines. 
This is what i have: 
td class="A-z(</td>)

Comment: as a bit of a tldr, there are some functional solutions that may work in your case but in the general case there are countless edge cases you will need to deal with as html isnt a regular language

Comment: Have you considered using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead of Regex?

Comment: You've already specified the question's tags in the tags field. The title field is for writing... a title.